# jquery checkboxes, how to get all selected checkboxes and add them to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have the following page:

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit1" id="1"  class="box">Banana<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit2" id="2"  class="box">Cherry<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit3" id="3"  class="box">Strawberry<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit4" id="4"  class="box">Orange<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit5" id="5"  class="box">Peach<br /><br />
<input type="button" id="groupdelete" value="clickme"><br />
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#groupdelete').on('click', function(){
  var names = [];
   $('input:checked').each(function() {

       names.push($('input:checked').attr("name") + $('input:checked').attr('id'));

 });
   console.log(names); 
})

})
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

To add the checked checkboxes in the array. And after that, I would like to be able to pass the value in php variable.

When I excecute the code now, I am getting result like this:

["fruit22", "fruit22", "fruit22"]

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, Zoreli

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `this` rather than `'input:checked'` inside the `.each()` function to refer to the current element in the set being examined. If you re-use the selector you're getting the set again, then only ever getting the attributes from the **first** element in the set.

```
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    names.push($(this).attr("name") + this.id);
});
```

Comment: Great, works like a charm...can you please tell me how could I pass this names array in php variable?

Comment: He can also use `this.name` instead of casting `this` back into a jQuery object. `prop` is preferred over `attr` as of jQuery 1.7+

Comment: And how to pass the value of names in php variable? Any idea?

Comment: Place 'names' into the value of a hidden input field and then read that from PHP when the form posts

Answer (score 1):

Change your html to

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits[]" id="1"  class="box">Banana<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits[]" id="2"  class="box">Cherry<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits[]" id="3"  class="box">Strawberry<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits[]" id="4"  class="box">Orange<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits[]" id="5"  class="box">Peach<br /><br />
<input type="button" id="groupdelete" value="clickme"><br />
```

And now, look to jQuery/Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#groupdelete').click(function() {
        var marked = new Array();
        var k = 0;
        $('input:checked').each(function(index,value) {
            marked[k] = value;
            k++;
        });        
        alert(marked[0].id);
    });
});
```

alert is just giving you the demo by accessing the direct access on the array's index.